# C++: How do I convert each char in a string into a corresponding character?

Tags: c++, encryption, key

I have a user inputted string `string date` (format DD-MM-YYYY) which I need to encrypt following this key 0=W, 1=x, 2=7, 3=%, 4=m, and so on...

When I input the following `12-06-1983`, this is the output I'm getting `012FFAD8` - which is wrong

According to the key, the output for `12-06-1983` should be x7dW#dx&4%

Below is my code, please help me figure out the error(s).
Furthermore, am I tackling this problem the correct way? Is there a simpler way to do this?
Please keep in mind, this is a beginner assignment in my C++ course.

```
string key = date;
string encryptedKey[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {

            if (key[i] == '0' ) {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'W';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '1') {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'x';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '2') {
                encryptedKey[i] = '7';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '3') {
                encryptedKey[i] = '%';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '4') {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'm';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '5') {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'G';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '6') {
                encryptedKey[i] = '#';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '7') {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'P';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '8') {
                encryptedKey[i] = '4';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '9') {
                encryptedKey[i] = '&';
            }
            else if (key[i] == '-') {
                encryptedKey[i] = 'd';
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nError.\n";
            }
        }

cout << encryptedKey;
```

Comment: `encryptedKey` shouldn't be an array of strings.

Comment: @John3136 Thank you.

Comment: A `switch` would be more readable, so would a table lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to replace `string encryptedKey[10]` by `string encryptedKey = "0000000000";` and your code works like expected. It's not smart, but it works.

Better of using nested if statements use switch-case.

In your code there is no need for if or switch-case. just use a map to translate your input string.

```
string key = "12-06-1983";
string encryptedKey = "";
map<char, char> replacements = {
    { '0', 'W' },
    { '1', 'x' },
    { '2', '7' },
    { '3', '%' },
    { '4', 'm' },
    { '5', 'G' },
    { '6', '#' },
    { '7', 'P' },
    { '8', '4' },
    { '9', '&' },
    { '-', 'd' }
};
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    encryptedKey += replacements.at(key[i]);
}

cout << "Key: " << encryptedKey;
```

The map defines which character is to replace with which other. Now just iterate over the input and lookup the map which character should placed inside the encryptedKey instead of the given.

Here is a working online example code by [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/5nesz)

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thanks for taking the time to type this out.

Comment: How would I add an error exception to this? For example, if the `key` has an illegal character like `Q` instead of a number. Would I do it outside this code or inside the map function?

Comment: It's already in there: The `at` method of the map object is throwing an exception if the key is not stored inside the map! If you wnat to handle it you just have to catch a `out of range` error.